# Sending ETX to NSTask

Tags: cocoa, nstask

I have an NSTask that's executing another program I wrote.  In that command line program, it expects the ETX (control-C, or ASCII value 3) to pause one of its processes and call another function.  How can I send this? I know I'm sending commands correctly because the program interacts with every command I've sent it so far except ETX.  I'm using the following code but it does not work:

```
NSString *cmdScan = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", 3];
[inputHandle writeData: [cmdScan dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(I'm assuming you want to emulate the behavior of the ctrl+c keystroke in a terminal window. If you *really* mean to send an ETX to the target process, this answer isn't going to help you.)

The ctrl+c keyboard combination doesn't send an ETX to the standard input of the program. This can easily be verified as regular keyboard input can be ignored by a running program, but ctrl+c (usually) immediately takes effect. For instance, even programs that completely ignore the standard input (such as `int main() { while (1); }`) can be stopped by pressing ctrl+c.

This works because terminals catch the ctrl+c key combination and deliver a `SIGINT` signal to the process instead. Therefore, writing an ETX to the standard input of a program has no effect, because the keystroke is caught by the terminal and the resulting character isn't delivered to the running program's standard input.

You can send `SIGINT` signals to processes represented by a `NSTask` by using the `-[NSTask interrupt]` method.

```
[task interrupt];
```

Otherwise, you can also send arbitrary signals to processes by using the `kill` function (which, mind you, doesn't necessarily kills programs).

```
#include <signal.h>
kill(task.processIdentifier, SIGINT);
```